# In a large dataset is there any fast way to identify the repeated data records and also bucket the records with similar repeat pattern in R?

Tags: r, duplicates

Assume I have a data frame as this:

```
my_df<- data.frame(mat1=c(1,2,2,2,1,2,2),
               mat2=c(5,4,3,1,5,4,4),
               mat3=c(4,1,6,9,4,1,1),
               mat4=c(1,2,6,9,1,2,2))
```

I actually know how to identify the repeats, which gives me the follwoing:

```
   mat1 mat2 mat3 mat4 Repeat
1    1    5    4    1   TRUE
2    2    4    1    2   TRUE
3    2    3    6    6  FALSE
4    2    1    9    9  FALSE
5    1    5    4    1   TRUE
6    2    4    1    2   TRUE
7    2    4    1    2   TRUE
```

I want to bucket the similar pattern, to generate the classes as follows:

```
  mat1 mat2 mat3 mat4 Repeat repeat_class
1    1    5    4    1   TRUE            1
2    2    4    1    2   TRUE            2
3    2    3    6    6  FALSE            0
4    2    1    9    9  FALSE            0
5    1    5    4    1   TRUE            1
6    2    4    1    2   TRUE            2
7    2    4    1    2   TRUE            2
```

where, repeat_class=0 shows non-repeated data records,repeat_class=1,2,etc identifies the similar paterns found in the data records.

I can do it in for loops, but for a large dataset it is just taking too long. I'm wondering if there is any faster way to do that in R?

Comment: You can check dplyr

Comment: *"bucket the similar pattern"* What does that mean?

Comment: Are the answers supposed to be number of repeats excluding the base row?

Comment: just editted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option with `.GRP` from `data.table`.  We group by the `names` of 'my_df', and assign (`:=`) `.GRP` values with number of rows greater than 1 to 'repeat_class'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_df)[, repeat_class := .GRP * (.N > 1), by = names(my_df)]
my_df
#   mat1 mat2 mat3 mat4 repeat_class
#1:    1    5    4    1            1
#2:    2    4    1    2            2
#3:    2    3    6    6            0
#4:    2    1    9    9            0
#5:    1    5    4    1            1
#6:    2    4    1    2            2
#7:    2    4    1    2            2
```

Comment: Thanks akrun! that's a neat solution

Comment: well I am aware of the fact that I have to vote on the best answer, the problem is that I am very new to this and therefore do not have sufficient reputation to be able to vote, I actually vote but it doesn't count :(

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want a column with a unique key for each repeat class in the data frame.

In dplyr, we can use the function `group_indices`:

```
library(dplyr)
my_df$repeat_class <- my_df%>%
    group_indices(mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4)

  mat1 mat2 mat3 mat4 repeat_class
1    1    5    4    1  1
2    2    4    1    2  4
3    2    3    6    6  3
4    2    1    9    9  2
5    1    5    4    1  1
6    2    4    1    2  4
7    2    4    1    2  4
```

To match your output, if we want non-duplicated keys to all match, we can set them to be 0:

```
my_df$repeat_class[!(duplicated(my_df$repeat_class) | duplicated(my_df$repeat_class, fromLast = T))] <- 0

  mat1 mat2 mat3 mat4 id repeat_class
1    1    5    4    1  1            1
2    2    4    1    2  4            4
3    2    3    6    6  3            0
4    2    1    9    9  2            0
5    1    5    4    1  1            1
6    2    4    1    2  4            4
7    2    4    1    2  4            4
```

Comment: Where are the 4's coming from?

Comment: looks like the order is not retained when assigning group keys using `group_indices` (presumably the function is hashing the groups keys and assigning after the hash), we will get keys upto and including the nunique number of rows, including the non duplicated ones. If desired, correcting to be an ordered unique key is left as an example for the reader :)

Comment: Thanks Jeremycg! that was what I was looking for. I can figure it out how to make it in order :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess (which mirrors my comment):

```
#Make a character vector that reflects the pattern:
my_df$pat <- apply(my_df,1,paste, collapse="_")
#Then use ave to measure length of each pattern and subtract 1 from the tally:
(my_df$repeat_class <- ave( seq(nrow(my_df)), my_df$pat, FUN=length ) - 1 )
#[1] 1 2 0 0 1 2 2
```